# TableAlias doesn't work with multiple joins

Tags: servicestack

`TableAlias` isn't working with multiple joins.

The query:

```cs
var q = Db.From<Blog>(Db.TableAlias("b"))
    .LeftJoin<Blog, BlogToBlogCategory>((b,btb)=> b.Id == btb.BlogId, Db.TableAlias("btbc"))
    .Join<BlogToBlogCategory, BlogCategory>((bt,bc)=>bt.BlogCategoryId == bc.Id, Db.TableAlias("cats"))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Id);
    .Select("b.*, json_agg(cats) as BlogCategoriesJson");

var results = Db.Select<BlogQueryResponse>(q);
```

Generates this SQL:

```sql
SELECT b.*, json_agg(cats) as BlogCategoriesJson
FROM "blog" "b" LEFT JOIN "blog_to_blog_category" "btbc" ON ("b"."id" = "btbc"."blog_id") INNER JOIN "blog_category" "cats" ON ("blog_to_blog_category"."blog_category_id" = "cats"."id")
GROUP BY "b"."id"
```

This causes error because it is referencing `"blog_to_blog_category"` instead of `btbc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Db.TableAlias()` only provides an alias for the target join table, your inner join does not specify the alias to use for the source table so it references the full table name as expected.

You can use `Sql.TableAlias()` in your LINQ Expression to reference a table alias, e.g:

```
var q = Db.From<Blog>(Db.TableAlias("b"))
    .LeftJoin<Blog, BlogToBlogCategory>((b,btb)=> b.Id == btb.BlogId, Db.TableAlias("btbc"))
    .Join<BlogToBlogCategory, BlogCategory>((bt,bc)=>
         Sql.TableAlias(bt.BlogCategoryId, "btbc") == bc.Id, Db.TableAlias("cats"))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Id);
    .Select("b.*, json_agg(cats) as BlogCategoriesJson");
```